# Googlebuzz url to buzz a text similar to twitter

Tags: twitter, google-buzz

With Twitter you can use http://twitter.com/home?status=sometext to twitter something. Is there a similar possibility for Googlebuzz?

Answer (score 1):

The [Post to Google Buzz API](http://code.google.com/apis/buzz/buttons_and_gadgets.html) is pretty easy to use.  You simply construct the URI like this:

`http://www.google.com/buzz/post?message={your_message}&url={your_url}`

There's also a JavaScript API that generates the buttons for you:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/buzz/post"
  class="google-buzz-button" title="Google Buzz"
  data-message="{your_message}"
  data-url="{your_url}"
  data-locale="en"
  data-button-style="normal-count"></a>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/buzz/api/button.js">
</script>
```